# Custom API advice - POST request advice with Yii framework

Tags: php, json, api, yii

I am working with another API (built by a different company) and they have provided me with a guide to use their API. It looks fairly straightforward, I just want to check a few things over to ensure I am doing this correctly, (I am currently using the Yii framework).

Below is an example request that for one one their API calls

```
{
"request" : {
    "model" : {
        "code" : "PR92DK1Z"
    }
}
```

In regards to this request would I be correct with the following:

```
Yii::app()->request->getPost('code');
```

My experience with custom API's is limited - thanks in advance

Comment: You must send it or it's a response?

Comment: sorry - it is a $_POST request (send)

Comment: So you need to form your request and send it via cURL. For example you can watch this https://github.com/ajimix/asana-api-php-class/blob/master/asana.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `code` value doing this:

```
$requestBody = Yii::app()->request->getRawBody();
$parsedRequest = CJSON::decode($requestBody);

$code = $parsedRequest["request"]["model"]["code"];
```

Comment: Can you suggest how to best test this? I mean - could I just add my json string above in your code to 'emulate' the real request?

Comment: Thanks - for this, my version of Yii is old and didn't have this function so i've extended it